# Can 2 instance of ServiceHost be in one application?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, servicehost

I have the app, where already there is the service.

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(*.*.*.*.com.MapViewPortTypeClient), new Uri(uri));
```

Can i create another instance of ServiceHost in this application, for example:

```
ServiceHost serviceHostKW = null;
serviceHostKW = new ServiceHost(typeof(*.*.*.*.com.ClientKW), new Uri(uriKW));
```

So after this it will be 2 services (servers) in this app. Will I have any problems?

Comment: You will have no problems. There was similar question
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419/how-to-host-2-wcf-services-in-1-windows-service/77401

Comment: you can have n-numer of service calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create as many `ServiceHost` instances, as you want.. but obviously url:port should be different

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! You can  Host Multiple  services in one solution with multiple endpoints and hosting. Go through this Link http://dotnetmentors.com/multiple-wcf-services-in-one-solution-with-multiple-endpoints-and-hosting.aspx hope it will be helpful.